# What is the proper way to send a DMCA to a hosting company?

Tags: legal, copyright, infringement, dmca

Someone copied my entire website and is hosting it at a domain name similar to ours. That website's content is copyrighted to the website which we have been running for years.

Each and every image, logo (including our company logo), content, link, graphic and layout have been copied. You could say the copied site is a perfect replica, just in a different domain.

The identity of the "alleged robber" has been blocked by [PrivacyProtect](http://www.privacyprotect.org/). I've sent emails with proof of the theft to `abuse@privacyprotect.org`. But each time they respond telling me that they cannot disclose the identity of the thief even though they say in their website that they will disclose the identity of any person who commits such illegal activities. Now PrivacyProtect is protecting his identity, whether they mean to or not.

After hours of Googling, I found I need to send a [DMCA take down notice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) to the host provider to take action. I would like few of my doubts to be cleared before send DMCA notice.

What is the format of sending DMCA take down notice to the host provider in this case?

Can I just type in the DMCA notice in an email or attach as a PDF in an email?

Should I need a lawyer to send it or I can send it myself?

Do I need any other attestation in the DMCA like attestation from notary public or judicial magistrate?

Comment: We worked hard for making our website up in the search engines and rankings. Now someone just copied and showing us what they got. Companies like privacyprotect are just for these guys doing illegal stuffs.

Answer (score 3):

I reworded your post and added a link, so that other readers and future visitors will know what the DMCA is.  After that I did a little Research regarding the format, and found a link on [How to Send a DMCA Takedown Notice](http://rising.blackstar.com/how-to-send-a-dmca-takedown-notice.html) from a Lawyer's Blog.  I hope this helps.  I'm sorry that this happened to you.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I am now preparing the DMCA notice and hope your link helps. Do you know sending a DMCA take down notice needs a lawyer/attorney to send it to the concerned hosting company or we can just make a pdf and email ?

Comment: The link I provided is for the situation you describe.  It is the General email format.  And just for proof purposes, I would send your evidence as a PDF attachment, but not the actual request.

Comment: Hi I'm sorry to hear that you're going through this. I am also currently going through similar. What I did was find out which host is hosting the site and then wrote a dcma letter via email to them. The did respond but it dies take a while. As it stands I waited since November last year and I've had to go directly to the owner of the host to get any sort of real action. He's assured me that they've taken the site down.

Comment: Find out their abuse email address and check their acceptable usage policy. Quite often it states in their that they'll terminate the account if found in breach. Best of luck. Let us know how you get on. And if they respond.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I am now preparing the DMCA notice, but I have difficulties in finding the host as different websites showing different hosts.

Comment: perform an NSLOOKUP, then Google for the owning Host of the values in the NameServer fields